# После обновления android studio до 2.3.3 появилась ошибка в gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, обновление

Сегодня обновила студию до версии 2.3.3, вроде все прошло хорошо, пустой проект собрался тоже без всяких ошибок. Но дальше.. Я открыла свой проект, над которым работа, и появилась ошибка

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'versionCode()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Mylti' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project 'Mylti' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin
>
> '

Что делать с этой ошибкой, как исправить?
вот код gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.blockly.demo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile project(':blocklylib-vertical')
}
```

Код основного gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Еще один gradle

```
  versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstruapply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mylti"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 25
            mentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':blocklylib-core-debug')
compile project(':blocklylib-core-release')
}
```

Comment: Приложите другой top-level gradle. если не сложно

Comment: @РасулA-ев вы можете рассказать, как это сделать? Так как я теряюсь.. У меня все работало в версии 2.2.3 , а теперь нет

Comment: У вас в проекте есть 2 gradle файла. Нужно выложить gradle на уровне приложения.

Comment: @РасулA-ев то есть мне нужно прописать какой - то код в основном gradle? А какой, можете подсказать?

Comment: Точно сказать не могу, поэтому и прошу выложить основной gradle

Comment: @РасулA-ев добавила код основного gradle

Comment: Вроде все нормально. Можете попробовать `Build`-> `Clean Project` и `Build`-> `Rebuild Project`

Comment: @РасулA-ев у меня есть еще один gradle  и ошибка теперь такая Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
 код добавлю сейчас к вопросу